# MongoDB Multiple documents update with Positional Array index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Having a collections as below:

```js
   [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ee111e541050ba2728adb3f"),
        "User" : "user1",
        "applications" : ["test1", "test2","test3"]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ee111e541050ba2728adb40"),
        "User" : "user2",
        "applications" : ["test1", "test3","test2"]
    }]
```

Expected Output:

```js
[{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ee111e541050ba2728adb3f"),
        "User" : "user1",
        "applications" : ["test1", "test2Updated","test3"]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ee111e541050ba2728adb40"),
        "User" : "user2",
        "applications" : ["test1", "test3","test2Updated"]
    }]
```

Used Below Query:

```js
db.getCollection('testUser').update({"applications":"test2"},
{$set:{"applications.$[elem]":"Test2Updated"}},
{ "arrayFilters": [{ "elem": "test2" }], "multi": true })
```

Not working in MongoDB 3.4
Any Solutions to make it work on MongoDB 3.4 could be helpful

Comment: `arrayFilters` are introduced in `3.6`, Do you've multiple `test2` element in `applications` array ?  Kind of can it be duplicated ? or does that exist only once in `applications` array..

Comment: Not Duplicates, User1 will also have application test2 and User2 will also have application test2 @whoami

Comment: actually my ask is can `test2` be repeated in `applications` array for a document !! You can check my answer..

Answer (score 1):

As [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#specify-arrayfilters-for-an-array-update-operations) was only introduced after `3.6` you need to do it in two update operations, We can use [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#examples?searchProperty=current&query=update) to achieve this in one DB call.

**Query :**

```
db.collection.bulkWrite([
  /** First push `test2Updated` element to applications array where `test2` exists */
  {
    updateMany: {
      filter: { applications: "test2" },
      update: { $push: { applications: "test2Updated" } }
    }
  },
  /** Remove `test2` from applications */
  {
    updateMany: {
      filter: { applications: "test2" },
      update: { $pull: { applications: "test2" } }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Note :**

Since we can't use `$set + $unset` both on array field at same time we've split this into two ops.

Also if you've multiple `test2` elements in same `applications` array use `$pullAll` to pull all of them out but you can't insert equivalent no.of `test2Updated` elements as you don't know how many `test2`'s exist for a document in that case you need to individually read docs to code and update `applications` array(I guess this is not the case).

One other thing is `test2Updated` will not be pushed to same index at which `test2` is but I guess this is not that important.